# Rspec/Capybara test post missing parameter from form but parameter is submmitted fine in dev when testing manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, post, rspec, capybara

One of my tests is creating a form post via javascript that is dropping the first input field from the form. The tests are obviously failing because of this. When deugging via binding.pry, it looks like a js post is dropping the first parameter [address_by_user] when posting it to my route. This parameter is posted just fine when testing via the ui in localhost but no longer works with rspec. Any idea what could cause this? Tests were passing as of two days ago and the forms haven't been changed. I tried restarting my computer in case it was a zombie process or something being cached, but the behavior continues. Any thoughts?

The form that is submitted via javascript using the following code:

```
          var form_id = "#form-step" + currentIndex; 
          var my_form = $(form_id);
          var url = $(form_id).attr('action');
          var form_data = my_form.serialize();
          console.log(form_data);
          var submission = $.post(url, form_data);
```

The form looks like this and is submitted after clicking the "Next" button in a wizard, that works fine.

```
<%= form_with(url:"add_property", scope: :property, class: "form", id:"form-step0") do |f| %>
      <div class="form-body" id="step0form">
      <h4 class="form-section"><i class="ft-location"></i> <%= t(:property_details) %></h4>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group pac-card col-md-8 offset-md-1 required" id='pac-card'> 
            <div class="field" id='pac-container'>
              <%= f.label :address_by_user, t(:address), class:"label-control" %>
              <%= f.text_field :address_by_user, :required => true, class: "form-control pac-input google-autocomplete", id:"pac-input" %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-row col-md-2">   
            <div class="field">
              <%= f.label :unit_number %>
              <%= f.text_field :unit_number, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-row">   
          <div class="field col-md-2 offset-md-1">
            <%= f.label :bedrooms %>
            <%= f.number_field :bedrooms, :required => true, class: "form-control", in: 1...20 %>
          </div>
          <div class="field col-md-2 offset-md-1">
            <%= f.label :bathrooms %>
            <%= f.number_field :bathrooms, class: "form-control", in:1...10 %>
          </div>
          <div class="field col-md-2 offset-md-1">
            <%= f.label :accommodates %>
            <%= f.number_field :accommodates, class: "form-control", min: "0" %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-row">
          <div class="field col-md-2 offset-md-1"><%=label_tag(t(:property_type))%></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-row" data-toggle="buttons">
          <div class="btn-group col-md-12">
            <div class="field col-md-2 offset-md-1">
              <%= f.label :room_type, class: 'text-center btn btn-default active' do %>
                <%= image_tag('house-icon.png') %>
                <br>
                <%= f.radio_button :room_type, "entire_place", checked: true %>
                <span>Entire Place</span>
              <% end %>
            </div>
            <div class="field col-md-2 offset-md-1">
              <%= f.label :room_type, class: 'text-center btn btn-default' do %>
                <%= image_tag('room.png') %>
                </br>
                <%= f.radio_button :room_type, "private_room" %>
                <span>Private Room</span>
              <% end %>
            </div>
            <div class="field col-md-2 offset-md-1">
              <%= f.label :room_type, class: 'text-center btn btn-default' do %>
                <%= image_tag('people.png') %>
                </br>
                <%= f.radio_button :room_type, "shared_room" %>
                <span>Shared Room</span>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="hidden-fields">
          <%= f.hidden_field(:latitude, id: 'latitude') %>
          <%= f.hidden_field(:longitude, id: 'longitude') %>
          <%= f.hidden_field(:street_number, id: 'street_number') %>
          <%= f.hidden_field(:street_name, id: 'route') %>
          <%= f.hidden_field(:city, id: 'locality')%>
          <%= f.hidden_field(:state, id: 'administrative_area_level_1') %>
          <%= f.hidden_field(:country, id: 'country')%>     
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

When tested directly from the site via localhost, all parameters post fine and I get this: (as expected)

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"address_by_user"=>"Pura Uvita Vacation Home, Puntarenas Province, Uvita, Costa Rica", "unit_number"=>"", "bedrooms"=>"2", "bathrooms"=>"2.0", "accommodates"=>"6", "room_type"=>"entire_place", "latitude"=>"9.1839769", "longitude"=>"-83.72444630000001", "street_number"=>"", "street_name"=>"", "city"=>"Uvita", "state"=>"Provincia de Puntarenas", "country"=>"Costa Rica"} permitted: false>
```

When the parameters are obtained via binding.pry from the rspec flow, the following is the result:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"unit_number"=>"", "bedrooms"=>"2", "bathrooms"=>"2", "accommodates"=>"6", "room_type"=>"entire_place", "latitude"=>"", "longitude"=>"", "street_number"=>"", "street_name"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>"", "country"=>""} permitted: false>
```

Answer (score 0):

The two most likely causes of this are

1. The fields are no longer actually being filled in - look at the browser while the tests are running and see if the form is actually being correctly filled in.
2. You have an error in another JS file causing the JS you think is processing the form not to run. This can happen because JS assets are concatenated in the test environment, allowing an error in on JS file to prevent any files concatenated after it not to be processed.

Comment: The form is being filled in and there are no is errors reported while looking at the console. The error has stopped happening after many reboots and restarts. It's still unclear why this behavior started though.

Comment: @Andrea There has to have been a change other than reboot, possibly in an external resource your app depends on (external JS, browser version, etc).

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm thinking probably happened. It's really odd. I still don't know what caused it, why it started or how it stopped.